# MySQL para Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Gostaria de transformar esse código em MySQL

```
SELECT pets.nome, pets.pulseira AS pets , localizacao.datahora, 
   localizacao.latitude, localizacao.longitude AS localizacao FROM pets 
   JOIN localizacao ON 
        localizacao.localPetID = id_pet where pets.id_pet  = 1
```

em uma sintaxe do sequelize.

Até agora o que consegui foi isso daqui:

```
pet.Pet.findAll({
        //selecionando os atributos nome e pulseira
        attributes: [
            'nome',
            'pulseira'
        ],
        //informando quais os valores para busca
        where: {
            nome: nomePet,
            pulseira: pulseira
        }
    }).then((pet) => {
        res.render('index', { pet: pet })
    })
```

eles está me retornando apenas o nome e numero da pulseira, porém, preciso que venha junto os dados de `datahora`, `latitude` e `longitude` para exibir.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar os relacionamentos, é necessário defini-los corretamente no model de cada tabela. Após criar os relacionamentos você deve passar a propriedade "include" no objeto da pesquisa. Ex:

```
return pet.Pet.findAll({
            attributes: ['nome', 'pulseira'],
            include: [{
                model: sequelize.models.localizacao,
                as: 'localizacao',
                attributes: ['latitude', 'longitude'],
                required: true
            }],
            where: {
                nome: nomePet,
                pulseira: pulseira
            }
        }).then(pet => res.render('index', { pet }));
```